# Bootstrap navbar - Options menu above logo

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The navigation bar contains the brand image between menu options. When in responsive mode, resizing the menu options appear above the image logo.

[image]

I think that an option will be to convert it to toggle navigation-bar. Is there any another option?

The code:

```
<div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar9">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="brand-centered">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img style="margin-right: 10px; padding: 0;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"/></a>
          </div>

          <div id="navbar9" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION EXAMPLE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION EXAMPLE</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION EXAMPLE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION EXAMPLE</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
```

The css:

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 60px;
}
.brand-centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.brand-centered .navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/dcodesys/5zLt9e5b/](https://jsfiddle.net/dcodesys/5zLt9e5b/1/)

Comment: cannot replicate on jsfiddle sorry, it's working fine there.

Comment: Another option could be using two different navigation bars. You can use these class: (hidden-xs, visible-xs)

Comment: @Elie Nassif I have updated the link, sorry!

Comment: @rumar I don't understand what you want. I just want to ask you : 1. Where the logo position on mobile screen size.  2) Where the logo position on desktop screen size.

Comment: @Ridoan Saleh Nasution I don't want to appear above the menu options in the image logo. You can see the image, the text of the menu option example is over image logo.

Comment: @rumar Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one. I'm not sure if this is what you expected. 
Let me know later if this meets your expectation.

The **logo** & *menu* positions on navbar :

1. Small device (smartphone and tablet) => **logo** on the left side & *menu* on the toggle-collapsed bar.
2. Large device (desktop) => **logo** on the left side & *menu* on the right side

```css
a.navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img alt="Brand" class="img-responsive" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty-office-part14-2/256/logo_yellow-32.png">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```